# auto.arima and parameter estimation

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am using the auto.arima function from the package forecast in R to forecast/simulate a AR(4), a MA(4) and a ARMA(2,2) model. The orders for the models are chosen based of the Akaike Information Criterion (in this function).
But how does this function estimate the values of the parameters? I read the documentation for auto.arima but i can't find the method used for parameter estimation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, `auto.arima()` has argument:

- **approximation**: If TRUE, estimation is via *conditional sums of squares* (CSS) and the information criteria used for model selection are
  approximated. The final model is still computed using *maximum
  likelihood estimation* (CSS-ML).

`auto.arima()`  uses the standard `arima()` function from the `stats` package, which offers 3 methods:

- **method** = c("*CSS-ML*", "*ML*", "*CSS*")

So it goes like this:

- The candidate models are estimated with "CSS-ML" or "CSS"
- The final model is estimated with "CSS-ML", i.e. Maximum-likelihood estimation (ML) where starting values for the optimisation are searched for via conditional sums of squares (CSS).

Comment: So in short, we can say the method uses Maximum Likelihood estimation for the parameters. Am I right with that?

Comment: You are right. I edited the text to make this clear, hope it is good now? If yes you are welcome to mark as accepted answer.